# Sample data to design LongListSelector WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I need to create markup for a `LongListSelector`. How can I bind data to the list at design time, so that I can play around with margins and stuff. All resources bind data when the application is run, and I don't (yet) have Blend that some of the links point to.
Is there any way to design the list using some static data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set design-time `DataContext` to your sample data in page definition:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d"
   d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance IsDesignTimeCreatable=True, Type=yournamespace:classwithdata}"
```

Then data from `classwithdata` will be populated on that page in `Visual Studio` or `Expression Blend` designer